# A doubt about Kirchhoff's scalar diffraction theory

Tags: optics, electromagnetic-radiation, diffraction

Scalar diffraction theory assumes a scalar wave equation of the form $$\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial t^2}=\nabla^2u$$ where $u(\vec{r},t)$ is a scalar field called the optical disturbance. But the electromagnetic field is a vector field and the wave equation required to be solved is  $$\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2{\vec E}}{\partial t^2}=\nabla^2{\vec E}$$ where ${\vec E}({\vec r},t)$ is the electric field vector, a vector function. What is going on? How should we think about $u$ if it's not the electric field?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a model. All models have limitations. Sometimes, a scalar wave model is adequately insightful for a vector wave problem, sometimes it isn't. A scalar model of light diffraction is fine for a camera lens, not so good for a narrow slit.